# Cannot resolve `before` in date

Tags: android

I wanted to check whether a date is before the current date.

I tried the below code but its showing an error Cannot resolve method before (java.util.date). Can anyone help me.

```
if(date2.before(date1)) {
    data.setError("Select a proper date");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please show your imports and how you initialize the variables date1 and date2

Comment: Have you tried to clean AS cache, and clear and rebuild the project as it can be an Android Studio issue?

Comment: use import java.util.Date;

Comment: it looks like your `date2` is not the type you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure date2 really is a Date:
For example:

```
Date date = new Date(10, 4, 20);
Date date2 = new Date(14, 2, 20);

boolean before = date2.before(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your date and dateformat to this method :

```
public static boolean checkValideDate(String date, DateFormat df) {
        Date currentDate = null;
        try {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            currentDate = df.parse(date);
            return android.text.format.DateUtils.isToday(c.getTimeInMillis())
                    || currentDate.after(c.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```